# what's the simplest way to write a dynamic column name using ADF copy activity mapping using a variable?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using a copy activity to write a JSON object of form `{"name" : 1}` except I now need to make "name" dynamic like "name" + current datetime so the JSON would look like `{"name2021-01-11": 1}`. I am setting the "current datetime" in a variable called `current_date` and id like to just have something like `@concat("name",variable)` in my copy activity mapping. This pattern seems to come up a lot but I have no good workaround.

I see "dynamic content" under mapping in the copy activity but it seems I can't just add an expression like `"$(@concat("name",my_date)"` using the data factory expression language. I'm hoping there is a workaround someone could help me clearly understand how to implement.

Comment: Are you copying the json file({"name" : 1}) from source to destination?

Comment: It's not copy activity, but it can be done using mapping data flows and column pattern matching in for example a derived column transformation

Comment: I would say do not use JSON like that.  The point of JSON is to represent objects or things.  An object has properties, or attributes.  So an object called `thing` would have attributes of `someDate`.  Do not build the date into the object name - there is no such thing as `thing2021-01-12`.  Even if you could build your JSON like this, how do you read it?  You would have to build completely custom code to read it every time or rely on some kind of wildcarding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @Cedersved said, it only can be done using mapping data flows and column pattern matching in for example a derived column transformation.

1. The source is as follows, a json file:
   [image]
2. Add a parameter named `datetimestr` and its default value is `toString(currentDate())`.
   [image]
3. At `DerivedColumn1` activity, click `add column pattern`. We can use  `position == 1` to specify the column and use `concat($$,$datetimestr)` to get the column name.
   [image]
   It's data preview will look like as follows:
   [image]

Comment: Hi @gtesfda, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.